# why I get in Z1 2 columns instead of 3 and how to fix it using hotEncoder

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm using hotEncoder for a column with 5 values witch gave me  5 columns (for Z). That's OK
now I have another column with has 3 values but I got 2 columns instead of 3 in Z1
what I need to do in the code to fix that I'll get 3 columns in Z1?

also, I would like the explanation for the hotEncoder code. Why I have to use np.hstack here?
Thank you very much!!

```
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values 
Y = df.iloc[:, -1].values 

labelencoder_X5 = LabelEncoder()
labelencoder_X6 = LabelEncoder()

X[:, 5] = labelencoder_X5.fit_transform(X[:, 5])
X[:, 6] = labelencoder_X6.fit_transform(X[:, 6])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
Z= onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, [5]])
X = np.hstack(( Z, X[:,:5] , X[:,6:])).astype('float')
#handling the dummy variable trap
X = X[:, 1:]

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
Z1= onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, [6]])
X = np.hstack(( Z1, X[:,:6] , X[:,7:])).astype('float')
#handling the dummy variable trap
X = X[:, 1:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `Z1` by transforming the 6th column, but *that is not the sixth column from the original data*.  In the previous block of code, you've put the 5th (original) column's dummy variables first when redefining `X` with the `hstack`.

But, some generic comments are in order.

- You do not need to label-encode before onehot-encoding; that's an artifact from old sklearn versions.
- You can use use a single `OneHotEncoder` and `fit_transform` both of your categorical columns in one go.
- You can use parameter `drop='first'` to "handle the dummy variable trap" inside `OneHotEncoder`.
- You can use `ColumnTransformer` to avoid manually using `hstack`.

That is, I'd suggest instead:

```py
tfmr = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('ohe', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False), [5,6])], 
    remainder='passthrough'
    )
X_preproc = tfmr.fit_transform(X)
```